# Is it possible to turn off the XBox One Kinect?

Tags: kinect, xbox-one

If the Kinect is disconnected from the XBox One, is the console still usable? (Does unplugging the Kinect render the console inoperable?)

Is it possible to turn off of disable the Kinect, or is it always on when it's connected.

A buddy of mine says that some sports games assess in game penalties if the Kinect hears swear words.  Is he pulling my leg, or is this a real thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> If the Kinect is disconnected from the XBox One, is the console still
>   usable? (Does unplugging the Kinect render the console inoperable?)

- **No, your Xbox One will still function properly** (just without the features the kinect uses (voice commands, facial recognition, etc)).  I set mine up initially without the kinect connected.  You will just see a symbal in the top right corner of your screen saying that your kinect is disconnected.

> Is it possible to turn off of disable the Kinect, or is it always on when it's connected.

- [You can disable features of the kinect without unplugging it.](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/kinect/turn-kinect-features-on-or-off)

> A buddy of mine says that some sports games assess in game penalties
>   if the Kinect hears swear words. Is he pulling my leg, or is this a
>   real thing?

- Yes, but not necessarily all games as that is up to the game developer / game settings.  [Source & video of this.](http://www.geekwire.com/2013/xbox-kinect-hear-curse-playing-nba-2k14/)

[image]

Comment: Surely these swearing recognition thing must be possible to toggle off? Sort of like disabling the profanity filter in online games.

Comment: Just learn to swear in different languages.

Comment: The developers/team who'm got that job had a good day.

Answer (score 1):

If it's disconnected the console will still work (any games that rely on it of course will not.)

Microsoft had initially made it mandatory but relented in August.

Yes, in FIFA 13 and 14 at least, swearing will get you carded.

Comment: I'm not convinced they relented (Abandoned or mitigated a harsh intention or cruel treatment); capitulated seems more apt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the console without kinect plugged in like normal. just without the kinect features (obviously). In some cases the console might complain about kinect not being plugged in (like when trying to use skype for example), but most gaming and menu navigation can still be done without kinect.

It's true that Kinect listens to you while playing games and reacts accordingly. This feature has become viral in [NBA 2K14](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/technology-science/technology/watch-xbox-kinect-punishes-user-2878226), but it is a simple game setting you can toggle if it bothers you.